# Finding an (logic) app based on the HTTP POST URL

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am currently facing an issue, which includes a Power App and a SharePoint list. My predecessor unfortunately didn't leave any info on that matter, so I try to figure it out myself. Anyway: In this SharePoint list, there is a single column, which is not filled as the others. Supposedly, this does not take place when creating a new object with the app. So I think there might be some flow that does this somehow, after the row is created. I actually found a flow in PowerAutomate, which seems to update the said SharePoint list. In it, there are several HTTP Post mudules. So I noted the numbers of the URLs ("https://prod-**194**.wes..." for example) and looked first in PowerAutomate and turned then to LogicApps, but except for one, I have failed to find the other flows, these HTTP requests are supposed to trigger. So I wonder, whether there is an easyer way to find these HTTP triggered flows.

Comment: Sorry, just so I understand correctly, you want to list all LogicApps along with its associated HTTP trigger URL, is that right?

Comment: Hi Skin,

Yes, pretty much that. When I go to azure and then to the Logic App overview, I see 11 apps, but they seem to have other HTTPs triggering them.

Comment: @MilanPijanovic is it the consumption or standard plan logic apps that you are mentioning here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**List all LogicApps along with its associated HTTP trigger URL**

You can use PowerShell:

- **Get-AzResource** -ResourceType "Microsoft.Logic/workflows"
- **Get-AzLogicAppTriggerCallbackUrl**

Script is:

```
$logicApps = Get-AzResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Logic/workflows"

foreach ( $la in $logicApps) { 

    $trigger = Get-AzLogicAppTrigger -Name $la.Name -ResourceGroupName $la.ResourceGroupName;
        
    if ($trigger.Name -eq 'manual') { 
        $url = (Get-AzLogicAppTriggerCallbackUrl -Name $la.Name -ResourceGroupName $la.ResourceGroupName -TriggerName manual); 
        Write-Host ($la.ResourceGroupName +' - ' + $la.Name +' - ' + $url.Value); 
    }
    else {
        Write-Host ($la.ResourceGroupName +' - ' + $la.Name +' - ' + $trigger.Name );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Muriel,

That helped.


Have a good week ahead!

Best regards